# MySQL generate url using already assigned ID

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to generate URL in SQL database using already assigned auto_incremented ID

When a new form is submitted then SQL automatically generates and unique `lens_id` for me. How can I automatically add it there in this `lens_url`? (Picture below)

[image]

Comment: You have to post some code about the way to insert data into your table. Also, I don't know why you stores full URL in your database, but you maybe should think to generate these URL dynamically, because when the hostname or part of URL will change, all your records will be wrong.

Comment: if is it `auto_incremented` you'll need to first check the last lens_id, then add 1 to the returned number and then use it in lens_url. (talking in PHP).

Comment: Now if you really want to do that, you have to get the `lastInsertId()` of your `INSERT`, then `UPDATE` `lens_url` using the id.

Comment: @Syscall thanks, got it working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by creating a trigger on your table. Trigger is as follows,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `UpdateLensURL` BEFORE INSERT ON `your_table_name`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.lens_url= CONCAT('localhost:8888/lensview/post.php?id=', (
            SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT 
            FROM information_schema.TABLES 
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() 
            AND TABLE_NAME = 'your_table_name'
      ));
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two options here:

1) Use a stored procedure (which will require code changes for anywhere that inserts rows)

2) Use a trigger and insert as normal - something like below should do the trick:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER my_awesome_trigger
BEFORE INSERT 
ON your_table_name 

FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

DECLARE next_id int default 0;

SELECT auto_increment INTO next_id
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name = 'your_table_name'
AND table_schema = DATABASE();

SET NEW.lens_url = CONCAT('localhost:8888/.../', next_id);

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$qry1="insert into tablename(lens_name,lens_url,lens_category,lens_author,lens_discription,lens_repert)values('A','B','C','D','E','F')";// your query to insert data to table
mysqli_query($con,$qry1); // run query
$last_insertid=mysqli_insert_id($con); // save last insetred ID
$url="localhost:8888/lenseview/post.php?id=".$last_insertid; //prepare url
$qry2="upadte tablename set lens_url=$url where lens_id=$last_insertid"; //update query 
mysqli_query($con,$qry2); // run your query to update url
```

Answer (score 0):

I think easiest option would be this

```
$Last_Lens_IdQ = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `lens_id` FROM `table` ORDER BY `lens_id` DESC LIMIT 1");
$Last_LensId = mysqli_fetch_array($Last_Lens_IdQ);
$x = $Last_Lens[0]++;
$LensUrl = "localhost:8888/lenseview/post.php?id=".$x;
```

Then insert the field and use `$LensUrl` When inserting the lens url column